# objective c avaudioplayer not playing sound

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am using this function to play sound on my iPhone app. the problem is that the sound isn't playing. the function works correct and read the file path correctly and I don't get any error but the sound does not play

```
-(void) playSound : (NSString *) fName; {
    if ([audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
        [audioPlayer stop];
    }
    audioPlayer.volume = 1.0;
    soundpath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sounds/%@", fName];
    soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundpath  ofType: @"mp3"];
    soundURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    if (audioPlayer == nil){

    }
else {
    [audioPlayer play];
        if ([audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
            NSLog(@"%@", @"run");
     }
}
}
```

Comment: Have done [prepareForPlay:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/prepareToPlay) somewhere? Always read manual before using class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error: nil];
UInt32 route = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(route), &route);
```

I had as similar problem and adding this before calling the play it solved the problem for me.